# Flutter, pass object to viewModel trigger recreating of the widget

Tags: flutter, widget, state, setstate

I would like to pass a model to a widget and his viewmodel.
I use this widget for 2 purposes: Add a new item and Edit the item.
So i will pass an empty object in case of new item and an already filled object in case of an edit.
Here i create a new post:

```
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    CupertinoPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => CreatePost(PostPizza()),
                    ),
                  ).then((value) {
                    callback.call();
                  });
                },
```

Here i set the post in the viewmodel:

```
class CreatePost extends StatefulWidget {
  final PostPizza post;

  @override
  _CreatePostState createState() => _CreatePostState();

  CreatePost(this.post);
}

class _CreatePostState extends State<CreatePost> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Create Post Widget build called");
    PostsViewModel viewModel = Provider.of<PostsViewModel>(context);
    viewModel.setPost(widget.post);
```

Setting the post object will trigger the text controllers :

```
    acquaController.text = post.acqua ?? "";
    saleController.text = post.acqua ?? "";
    lievitoTipoController.text = post.lievito?.a ?? "";
    lievitoAmountController.text = post.lievito?.b ?? "";
```

This will trigger the widget to rebuild continiously.

Any idea how can i solve the issue without all this?
This will

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```dart
class _CreatePostState extends State<CreatePost> {
  bool isSet = false, isLoading = true;
  PostsViewModel? viewModel;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Create Post Widget build called");
  viewModel = Provider.of<PostsViewModel>(context);
if(isSet == false) {
     isSet = true;
    viewModel.setPost(widget.post);
    isLoading = false;
}
return ....
```

Comment: That's not gonna help. 
Do you know if i can pass a parameter in the provider? 
PostsViewModel viewModel = Provider.of<PostsViewModel>(context);

Comment: @SalvatoreLaFiura You can't. Meanwhile I have just update my answer and I have used this method before. You have to include a loading spinner to avoid null errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
viewModel = Provider.of<PostsViewModel>(context, listen: false);
```

It will not perform rebuild.

Updated Answer, it will be called once:

```
@override
void initState() {
  viewModel = Provider.of<PostsViewModel>(context, listen: false);
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    viewModel.setPost(widget.post);
  });
  super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print("Create Post Widget build called");
  /// Remove this:
  /// PostsViewModel viewModel = Provider.of<PostsViewModel>(context);
  /// viewModel.setPost(widget.post);
  
  /// ...
}
```

Comment: I even tried without a provider:     PostsViewModel viewModel = PostsViewModel( widget.post);
 
Still the widget keeps being rebuilt.

Comment: @SalvatoreLaFiura perhaps your parent widget is rebuilding

Comment: Possible, but how? just changing the data of a child widget?

Comment: @SalvatoreLaFiura maybe because your parent widget state changes. Try to `print(“something”)` in your parent `build()` method. 

If that print called, it means the problem is on your parent widget.

Comment: I don't really have a parent widget, this widget is pushed from the previous one.

Comment: Try to call this`viewModel.setPost(widget.post);` on `initState()` method. But wrap that code with **Future.delayed** or **SchedulerBinding** first and don’t forget to use `listen: false`. And remove that code from `build()` method.